# Nowadays US political standoff - is it a precedent for the US?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, democracy

U.S. internal political standoff is already existed for a while - in fact, since last Presidential Elections. Recently, I've seen something like [this](https://www.cnn.com/2020/02/06/politics/nancy-pelosi-state-of-the-union-reaction/index.html) as a culmination of that partisanship. I just don't have words for this - it was like 9/11.

I was always sure, that there is some unwritten rule in the US - despite any internal contradictions, the fighting isn't done publicly.

Is there precedent for such degree of **public** political standoff in the U.S.? Maybe I'm mistaking and that "rule" I've heard of, is just something recent, from the late 20th century.

Comment: *despite any inner contradictions, nothing of it is drawn to the public.* [Ahem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War). And there are many other, less dramatic examples (search for "nullification crisis")

Comment: @SJuan76, about Civil War - of course, agree. I thought about this example, but was not sure if it was the only one.

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkansas_National_Guard_and_the_integration_of_Central_High_School, to get a more modern example.

Comment: That's nothing.  In 1804, [the Vice President shot the Secretary of the Treasury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr%E2%80%93Hamilton_duel).

Comment: I think the most interesting part of this question is that the media narrative makes the ripping of a speech comparable to 9/11.

Comment: How is a politician's ripping a speech comparable to any sort of terrorist attack, let alone the most lethal one in US history? What is the analogous element here?

Comment: @JustMe, impressive example..

Comment: Unwritten rule in USA politics. Any scandal not involving death is a "gate" named after the infamous Watergate thing under Nixon. This should be "Nancy-gate" or "rip-gate" or some such.

Comment: @puppetsock Not just US politics - remember [deflategate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflategate)?

Comment: OP can you reask this question to exclude all of the anecdotes? As riveting as they may be, the plural of anecdote is not data. We need actual data to answer this properly. Example: https://www.visualcapitalist.com/charts-americas-political-divide-1994-2017/

Comment: As it stands now, I'm voting to close as this question has become hopelessly overrun with stories of caning on the Senate floor and similar irrelevant nonsense. You will never have a definitive answer of which act of shenanigans caused the "most drama"

Comment: @SurpriseDog, Closing this makes no sense for those of us with more faith in SE's mechanics...  First you give an example of what a good answer would include, (which demonstrates that the Q. really can be answered), *then* you close the Q. because of a few irrelevant answers.  Instead please just downvote the latter anecdotals, and either post your own systemic answer, or patiently upvote any better answers whenever those arrive.

Comment: Re *"this"* (*i.e.* the ripping):  context -- that gesture was preceded by the insult of turning a State of the Union speech into a maudlin award ceremony for [an infamously divisive broadcaster](https://newsone.com/16051/top-10-racist-limbaugh-quotes/) and golf buddy.

Answer (score 5):

Theatrical maneuvers are nothing new in politics in the USA. This particular event happened in 1867, in the Arkansas state legislature.

https://lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/c/changethename.html

The gentleman took out his pistol and laid it on the desk in front of him so he would not be interrupted. And he gave the following speech.

> Mr Speaker, god-damn your soul, for more than thirty minutes I've been trying to get your attention but every time I caught your eye you squirmed like a damn dog with a flea in his ass.
>
> I guess you know who I am Sir. My name is Cassius M. Johnson from Jackson County, Arkansas where a man  can't stick his ass out the window and shit without it getting riddled with bullets. Why Sir, I was  fourteen years old before I had my first pair of pants and they was of buckskin. But at the age of seventeen Mr Speaker, I had a jock on me the size of a roasting ear and it was the pride of Jackson County. And you propose to change the name of Arkansas. Never, by God Sir, never!
>
> I'm out of order? How can I be out of order when I can piss clear across the Mississippi River?
>
> Where was Andrew Jackson when the battle of New Orleans was fought? He was right thar Sir, up to his ass in blood. And you change the name of Arkansas? Never, when I can defend her.
>
> You may shit on the grave of George Washington. Piss on the monument of Thomas Jefferson. You may desecrate the sacred remains of the immortal General Robert E. Lee. You may rape the Goddess of Liberty and wipe your ass on the Stars and Stripes. And your crime, your crime Sir will no more compare to this hellish design than the glow of a lightning-bug's ass to the glare of the noon days sun. And you propose to change the name of Arkansas. Never, by God Sir, never!
>
> You may compare the lily of the valley to the glorious sunflower. Or the sun-kissed peaks of the highest mountains to the smokin' turd of a dunghill. Or the classic strains of Mozart to the fart of a Mexican burrow. You may compare the puny penis of a Peruvian prince to the ponderous buttocks of the Roman gladiator. But change the name of Arkansas? Never, by God Sir, never!

Comment: It's a great story, but it mainly involves idiosyncratic individuals, rather than being a systemic comparison of a more generalized US political standoff.

Answer (score 4):

Are we forgetting the Caning of Charles Sumner in 1856?   Senator Sumner (R-Mass.) was assaulted on the Senate Floor by Representative Preston Brooks (D-SC) while co-conspires Rep. Laurence M. Keitt (D-SC) and Rep. Henry A. Edmundson (D-VA) blocked other Senators from assisting in stopping the fight.   Brooks' attack was in retaliation for a speech in which Sumner accused Senator (and Brooks' cousin) Andrew Butler (D-SC) of wishing to keep slaves in order to sexually force himself on slave women (this was not the first time such charges had been lobbed in the Abolition debate, and Pro-Slavery politicians would attack the sexual morals of Abolitionist in kind.).

Sumner was temporarily blinded during the attack and for the remainder of his life suffered from pain and emotional damage from the attack that today is known consists with traumatic brain injury and PTSD.  In fact, during the attack, many Senators pleaded with Brooks to not kill Sumner, and the attack stained the floor of the Senate with Sumner's blood.

As it was an election year, and occured during the height of the Bleeding Kansas crisis, Republicans used the attack slogan "Bleeding Kansas and Bleeding Sumner" to call out the democrats barbarism and while Brooks challenged two more Republicans to duels, one accepted, but chose weapon of Rifles and the battleground of "the Canada side of Niagara Falls" and another refused on the grounds that such an act was barbaric and elected to highlight Brooks' further barbarism (Note:  At the time, Dueling was outlawed in the United States, so the later politician was refusing on the grounds that he would not perform an illegal act... the former was a noted crack shot and knew that under Canadian law at the time, dueling was perfectly legal... Brooks did not follow through on the acceptence, citing dangers of traveling through the Northern States... but likely realized the person who challenged him was probably going to kill him and get away with it.).

For some time after the attack, several members of Congress carried weapons on them out of an abundence of caution.  That said, physical attacks between U.S. legislators is very very rare, so it stands out.   This is not to say that Nancy Pelosi's ripping of the State of the Union is justified, but that she merely qualifies for the "Not as Big of a Jerk as you could have been" Award.

Answer (score 1):

That is nothing compared to what has happened between parties in the past. Just look back to the Obama years and efforts to block him. Ripping up a copy of a speech is nothing compared to working to prevent someone from getting reelected by blocking everything they want to do.

https://www.politico.com/story/2010/10/the-gops-no-compromise-pledge-044311

> But that’s Tuesday. Right now, the tone is a lot different — with Republicans pledging to embrace an agenda for the next two years that sounds a lot like their agenda for the past two: Block Obama at all costs.
>
> Here’s John Boehner, the likely speaker if Republicans take the House, offering his plans for Obama’s agenda: “We're going to do everything — and I mean everything we can do — to kill it, stop it, slow it down, whatever we can.”
>
> Senate Minority Leader Mitch McConnell summed up his plan to National Journal: “The single most important thing we want to achieve is for President Obama to be a one-term president.”

https://www.huffpost.com/entry/mitch-mcconnell-blocks-obama-laughs_n_5df32430e4b0deb78b517322

> Senate Majority Leader Mitch McConnell (R-Ky.) on Thursday night bragged about blocking President Barack Obama’s attempt to fill federal judicial vacancies for two years. Then, he laughed about it as he discussed the Republican Party’s effort to stack the courts with conservative judges under President Donald Trump.
>
> “I was shocked that former President Obama left so many vacancies and didn’t try to fill those positions,” Fox News host Sean Hannity said to McConnell.
>
> Obama didn’t leave those vacancies so much as he was blocked from filling them by a GOP-controlled Senate led by McConnell ― something the majority leader was quick to point out.
>
> “I’ll tell you why,” he said. “I was in charge of what we did the last two years of the Obama administration.”

Comment: Really, really bad examples. Was President Obama obligated to nominate judges the Republican Senate wanted?  Of course not. Ergo, it follows that the Republican Senate was not obligated to confirm the judges President Obama nominated. Note that McConnell did not publicly rip up any of the papers that transmitted President Obama's nominations to the Senate.  Refusing to confirm a nomination over political differences is a far cry from a public display of disrespect bordering on a three-year-old's temper tantrum.  Or a duel with pistols where one duelist is killed.

Comment: @JustMe They are responsible to advise and consent on all presidential appointments and having a policy to block all of them goes in the face of that duty. The same can be said for working on policies that the president wants to implement.

Comment: As someone once said, elections have consequences.

Comment: @JustMe The consequences of elections is not that the elected officials can refuse to do the job such as not confirming judges and leaving the court system overworked because there are courts that have no judge and can't do work.

Comment: @JustMe In the end it is the duty of every elected official to work with other elected officials regardless of political affiliation

Comment: So you're saying President Obama failed to do his job because he didn't "work with" the Senate to nominate judges that they would confirm?  I agree.

Comment: @JustMe I am saying that the senators who stated on record multiple times that they wanted to make Obama a one term president and block everything he does where not doing their job. This is an example of members of congress disrespecting the other party by publicly stating they will do everything they can to oppose them.

Comment: So Nancy Pelosi was also "not doing her job" by trying to make President Trump less than a one-term President?   Glad you also agree that this is also an example of the Speaker of the House "not doing her job": [**Pelosi Says House Will Move Swiftly to Block Trump’s National Emergency on Wall**](https://www.wsj.com/articles/pelosi-says-house-will-move-swiftly-to-block-trumps-national-emergency-on-wall-11550716942)

Comment: (cont)  Because if trying to impeach Trump and blocking his agenda are not also examples of elected officials "not doing they jobs" by the same argument you just stated, your definition of "doing their job" is incredibly one-sided.

Comment: @JustMe - Trying to impeach and remove Trump for what the majority of the House considered to be impeachable offenses _was_ Pelosi's job.  If you disagree with their conclusions, it's perfectly valid to argue that Pelosi and the House showed poor judgement in deciding _what_ was an impeachable offense, but it was literally her Constitutionally-mandated job to impeach for an impeachable offense.

Comment: @JustMe I never said that her trying to block Trump was okay. But you seem to be saying what happened when Obama was in office was okay but are now getting upset at what is happening while Trump is in office?

Comment: @Bobson And if "Trying to impeach and remove Trump for what the majority of the House considered to be impeachable offenses was Pelosi's job", then **NOT** confirming judges the majority of the Senate deemed unacceptable was the Senate's job.  Another "doing their job" description that is incredibly one-sided.  And show me where McConnel publicly destroyed the paperwork Obama submitted.

Comment: @JustMe There is a difference between the leadership not bringing up appointments for vote and the members voting to not approve them because they do not agree with the appointment. What is being referred to here is the blanket holding up of approval of appointments and not turning them down based on issues with each one.

Comment: @JustMe Refusing consent for a judge would mean the Senate was doing their job. Refusing consent for a judge simply because of who nominated them rather than the judge's actual qualifications and fitness for the office can be considered to be doing their job _badly_, but it's still doing it. Not even holding a vote is explicitly *not* doing the job. The requirement for the Senate is to provide "advice and consent". Refusing consent is a valid option; refusing to reply at all is not. My rule on this is consistent: If you _act_ you're doing the job, even if poorly. If you don't act, you're not.